# Click and change the class of a header with add/removeClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to allow the user to click between 1-4 options. They can pick one or all 4.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YV8gb/9/) .

```
<a class="selector" href="#"><h2 class="unselected">Option 1</h2></a>
<a class="selector" href="#"><h2 class="unselected">Option 2</h2></a>
<a class="selector" href="#"><h2 class="unselected">Option 3</h2></a>
<a class="selector" href="#"><h2 class="unselected">Option 4</h2></a>

$("a.selector").click(function(){
    $(this).children("h2").removeClass('unselected').addClass('selected');
});
```

It's a simple, but I can't get it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you working just in the fiddle? If so, you did not select jQuery. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheJoeFletch/YV8gb/11/)

Comment: [See adjusted fiddle, it works](http://jsfiddle.net/CjCM4/)

Comment: `.toggleClass()` would also allow to unselect. Just saying. http://jsfiddle.net/CjCM4/1/

Comment: I answered but if OP confirms it's OK, I think this should be closed as "too localized".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works as soon as you add jQuery to the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/CjCM4/

No need to change the code :

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $(this).children("h2").removeClass('unselected').addClass('selected');
});
```

​

(see menu on the left)

Comment: Doesn't it bother you that you *had* to post the code to bypass the "no jsfiddle link without code [filter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151616/167534)"?

Comment: Yes it does. But maybe it means that this question should be closed (in fact I immediately deleted my answer and undeleted it only because there were bad other ones). I voted to close. I'm not totally sure of my opinion both regarding the question and the new filter.

Comment: You're right, definitely too localized IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I just update your code on jsfiddle

```
/*​$('a.selector').on('click', function(){
   $(this).children("h2").removeClass('unselected').addClass('selected');
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​*/

$('a.selector').on('click', function(){
   $(this).children("h2").toggleClass('selected');
});
```

​

Answer (score 0):

You have your fiddle set to Mootools like somebody said above switching it to jQuery will make it work.

working example:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/rbUjx/
```

Comment: In jsfiddle, the code you type is only called after the DOM is ready.